# Алгоритм Сапера на си шарп

Tags: c#, массивы

Написал консольное приложение сапер, но появились проблемы с реализацией. Мой алгоритм таков: есть массивы, один для показа клеток в консоли, в другом содержаться расположения мин(9-мина,0-8  соответственно кол-во мин рядом). При выборе одной из клеток, если клетка содержит 0, то проверяются все соседние клетки по порядку, а в массиве для показа этот ноль становится видимым, если те клетки содержат 0,то снова выполняется этот рекурсивный проход по клеткам и отображение в массиве для показа. Так вот, в случае если выбрана одна из клеток и она ноль, в клетке слева и сверху содержатся единицы,а в клетке сверху-слева находится ноль, то по идее этот ноль не должен отображаться,потому что к нему нет прямого доступа(то есть,с любых сторон кроме диагональных)Как мне реализовать это?

Comment: а чем плохи диагонали? мне кажется должны обрабатываться все ячейки вокруг.

Comment: представьте поле 6на6,в позициях (1,4) и (4,1) содержатся мины,теперь выбираем клетку на позиции (3,3). При обходе всех клеток сверху слева не должен быть тронут ноль

Comment: стоит поиграть в классического сапёра ;)

Comment: там другая реализация?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очень просто. При открытии 0-клетки ищите 0-соседей не по диагонали, а только сверху, снизу, слева и справа.